# Android virtual device not in Select Deployment Target

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have created a virtual device in Android Studio 2.2.3 for running my code. When I click the Run button, the Select Deployment Target dialog box appears, but it doesn't show my virtual device. What should I do? Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check min version for your application as well as the version of android on the virtual device

Comment: I appreciate your help but the min version of my application as well as the version of android on the virtual device are the same.

Comment: Does "adb devices" console command return your virtual device?

Comment: No, Alexander Bilchuk, instead it returns an error.